# Optimal way to handle loads upto 50K TPS using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

can JMeter distributed test handle such loads? or should we fire individual tests on each server and use a backend listener to store the details.
If both of them are not the optimal way, what is the best way to build load test infrastructure to handle big loads?

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations for the throughput (number of requests per second) on JMeter side, the question whether you can conduct the required load or no mainly depends on the hardware you can allocate.

Given you have powerful enough machine and follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you can even create such a load using single instance, however it's a good idea to check resources usage like CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO, etc. using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test). The idea is that JMeter must have enough headroom to operate as if it will not be able to send requests fast enough due to i.e. high CPU usage the perceived load will be less even if the system under test can handle more and you will get false negative results.

The answer to the question whether you need to use the Backend Listener mainly depends on the following criteria:

- do you need the possibility to [observe the test results in the real time while the test is running](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)
- do you need to store the results in some database instead of the [.jtl results files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

Comment: we observed a change in response times when running in distributed mode and running the tests separately and merging the jtl after the results. I've enough infra support to back my tests, but the question is whether JMeter distributed test support such huge TPS. Our jtl files are very huge. When we tested last time on one of the load testing platforms with around 20c5.18xlarge machines. Even they were not able to provide us with the results.

Comment: I'm a little skeptical about JMeter distributed testing above 10K tps.